# send parameters sort and filtrering from Ext.panel .Table

Tags: extjs

I am in a development on sencha jext 6.5.3, I need that when doing a search on a paginated table (shows the data of a remote end-point), keep the selected filters out of that table. I can't do it.

When I sort the table by a column, I don't know how to send a filter at the same time within the call a parameter that can filter the data (https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.panel .Table.html),

a sort parameter is sent, when filtering, how can I send other parameters, End Date???

[image: call end-point sort by fecha final , no filter with textfiel fecha final]

https://url.org/promotion?page=1&start=0&limit=25&sort=validityEndDate

This is the call.

With what property of Table can I pass a parameter `& dateFin =22/11/2019` to the end-point?

Comment: The filters should be kept by default. How do you set the filters to the grid (on "Aplicar" click)?

Comment: yes, right ... thanks, the form above filters the table data

Answer (score 0):

extraParams

every time it is filtered by some value we modify params, with the new filter

```
var promotionsStore = this.getViewModel().getStore('promotions');
 promotionsStore.getProxy().setExtraParams(params);
 promotionsStore.loadPage(1);
```